# Can you identify this blooming plant?

Tags: identification, botany

I found this plant and tried identifying it online based on leaves/buds but got no results.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The location is North East US, during the day, March 5, 2020.

Any idea what this plant is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks remarkably like *Viburnum pragense*, but its rather early for that to be starting to flower now, it usually does so in about 8 weeks time. If you've had a relatively mild winter wherever you are, that might explain why it's flowering early. Whilst described as having white flowers, the buds are pink, as you can see in your photograph. General information here http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=m770

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly the plant! Thanks Bamboo!